# How can I create a databricks programmatically?

Tags: c#, azure, databricks

I have used the databricks API to create users/groups, clusters, workspace folders, etc.

I have used the Azure API to create a resource group and a V2 storage resource, but I can't seem to figure out/find any documentation on how to create a databricks programmatically.

I have found some ways using Python, but I can't seem to find what package or any examples in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source repo for the C# SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/search?p=1&q=databricks&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93), I dont see any references to Azure DataBricks resource provider. Seems you can only create a DataBricks linked service in Azure Data Factory, thats it.

I dont see DataBricks in the [api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet) as well.

Seems it is impossible with native SDK methods. you can call the [rest api directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/createorupdate).

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed the REST API reference. That did it!